# Python write out itertools

Tags: python, multithreading, python-itertools

I would like to manually write out what itertools does in one line so that I can attempt to use multiple strings to work through the function quicker.  Right now this function works, I just need to massively speed it up.  I am not really even sure if writing out the itertools line would enable me to use multiple threads.

```
def list ():
charLength = sys.argv[2]
charSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

combo = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(charSet, int(charLength))
for floatingcombo in combo:
    floatingcombo = ''.join(floatingcombo)
    floatingcombo += "." + sys.argv[3]
    try:
        floatingIP = socket.gethostbyname(floatingcombo)
        msvcrt.printf("%s resolved to --> %s\n", floatingcombo, floatingIP)
    except socket.gaierror:
        msvcrt.printf("%s does not exist\n", floatingcombo)
return
```

Comment: Any such function you write in python will be slower than its `itertools` equivalent. This is because the code for many of the `itertools` functions are written in C. Also, you're not very clear as to which `itertools` function you're dealing with.

Comment: Your example code doesn't seem very ethical. I doubt sysadmins running DNS servers would be overjoyed by the load you intend to generate on their boxes.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here.  "one line"?  "multiple strings"?

Comment: As @isedev says the purpose of your script seems very dubious. 5 characters gives over 500K addresses. Are you trying to break the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably IO-bound. You could speed up the lookup by using multiple threads/processes. To avoid threading issues in dns implementation, you could use multiple processes to resolve hosts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
import socket
import sys
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def resolve(host, domain=""):
    host = ''.join(host) + domain
    try:
        return host, socket.gethostbyname(host), None
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        return host, None, e

def main():
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    size = int(sys.argv[2])
    resolve_host = partial(resolve, domain="." + sys.argv[3])
    combo = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(alphabet, size)

    pool = Pool(20) 
    for host, ip, error in pool.imap_unordered(resolve_host, combo):
        if error is None:
           print("%s resolved to --> %s" % (host, ip))
        else: # error
           print("Can't resolve %s, error: %s" % (host, error))

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: I didn't even realize it could be that simple!  Wow, Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to accept J.F.Sebastians's answer do him the honour of up voting it as well.

Comment: @sotapme: There might be a reputation minimum required to upvote.

Comment: That's OK I gave you a bump - although I hope you've not helped someone break the interweb. :D